# I2C Mux on Linux

Tags: linux, i2c

I am trying to understand how to address devices behind `I2C Mux` like `PCA9548` in `linux`.
If the topology is something like

```
CPU->I2C_A Controller->PCA9548->Channel 0->RTC
CPU->I2C_A Controller->PCA9548->Channel 1->Temp Sensor

CPU->I2C_B Controller->PCA9548->Channel 0->Voltage Sensor
CPU->I2C_B Controller->PCA9548->Channel 1->Speed Sensor
```

I want to know the representation of these devices in user space? What are the associated sysfs entries?

I also want to know if `pc9548` is the only driver required in kernel and `i2c-dev` and `i2c-core` are already available? Or driver for RTC/sensors is also required?

I have tried to read [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/i2c/i2c-mux.c?id=51cf3b0e2a72bb08cd280be6c0ead4e08ed50a2c), but could not follow it much.

My requirement is to read/write to those devices from user space. Do I have to  instantiate devices and assign addresses to it in startup script?

Thanks,
Hemant

Answer (score 0):

You could use i2c-tools for manipulation at user space, if the driver has some problem.
Also you'll need enable the kernel module "i2c-dev" for the char device.
Like /dev/i2c-0
[link here.](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/I2CTools)

The necessary driver are i2c-mux, pca954x, I believe you already have i2c-core.
Also you should describe all the I2C devices in device tree or other files.

If the driver is prepared, you may see 8 i2c adapters under /dev, and their salve device is under /sys/bus/i2c.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is also a new_device/delete_device kind of sysfs associated with mux driver (/sys/bus/i2c/<adapter-id>/new_device) to create/delete devices behind MUX. In the newer kernel there is a also a channel-X kind of sysfs to be used for clear description of topology. See https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/i2c/i2c-mux.c?id=c9449affad2ae0824927df5a207705e07f346fb1